# LINQ Query: new query object with a Count element of another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Bellow is the LINQ query I am trying to operate

```
var custSelect = from m in _context.Entities
                         where m.Active == true && m.EntityTypeId == 1
                         orderby m.Name
                         select new { m.EntityId, m.Name, JobCount = _context.Jobs.Where(o => o.CustomerId == m.EntityId).Distinct().ToList().Count };
```

I want to be able to select a new selection variable as JobCount which is an integer counting how many jobs are attached to said customer.
Then later, during the model creation, I want to be able to then order by the Count variable for example.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You do a Join between to tables here, but there is no join in your query. You should do this explictly. To count something you need a group by. What you want to do if there are no Jobs existing ? This decides, whether you need an inner join or a left join.

Comment: Oh Ok yes, this worked for me. My code was just missing a join and a bit more. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way, [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zkdVjb) is the live demo

```
var result = (from e in entities
                  join j in jobs on e.EntityId equals j.CustomerId
                  where e.Active && e.EntityTypeId == 1
                  select new 
                  {
                      e.EntityId, 
                      e.Name,
                      j.JobId
                  }).GroupBy( p => new { p.EntityId, p.Name })
                    .Select(g => new 
                                {
                                    EntityId = g.First().EntityId, 
                                    Name = g.First().Name,
                                    JobCount = g.Count()  
                                })
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Please let me know if you need any help. @Aquaphor

Comment: Yes, this worked super well actually. It's a lot larger than I would have thought but it works perfectly. Marking this as the answer. Was busy over the Christmas holidays sorry :)